# Geometric intuition for why $R(A^T)=N(A)^\perp$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm having trouble visualizing *why* the range of $A^T$ is the orthogonal complement to the nullspace of A. I understand that this is the same as saying the row space of A is the nullspace$^\perp$, but I don't really *see* it. I can see why they are in the same space (i.e. $\mathbb{R}^n$ for an m$\times$n matrix) but I just don't know how to visualize the row space.

I understand this fact can be proven with inner product operations, but those do not help me see why this is the case.

Comment: What can you actually see anyway in $\Bbb R^n$ if $n\gg 3$?

Comment: How are you visualizing the column space of $A^T$?